# absolute child div to stay in parent

Tags: css, position, positioning, absolute

Trying to make a child div with the position absolute to expand the parent div that contains position relative.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stay in parent</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div>
            header
        </div>
        <div style="position:absolute;">
            content<br />
            content<br />
            content<br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="clear:both">
        footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The footer just stays ontop of content.

Comment: Sorry, absolute positioning doesn't work that way, maybe you should include a diagram of the layout you're trying to achieve and someone can show you how to do it.

Comment: Well, the div that has position absolute also has a display:none. When a button is clicked that div will show. I need that div to stay ontop of the main content div and have the wrapper expand w/ it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, may help you to understand the structure.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stay in parent</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:90%; border:#999999 1px solid; padding:2px;">
        <div style="width:99%; border:#3399FF 1px solid;padding:2px;">
            header
        </div>
        <div style="width:99%; float:left; border:#3399FF 1px solid;padding:2px; ">
            content<br />
            content<br />
            content<br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br clear="all" />
    <div id="footer" style="width:100%;border:#999999 1px solid;padding:2px;">
        footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```